# Centering Text In A TextView

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview, center

I have a TextView that has text Dynamically Added to it.  My problem is that when I use gravity for the centering the text, it doesn't move because the width is set to "wrap_content".

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to set the width to something other than "wrap_content".

Comment: The only other option is fill parent.

Comment: I wouldn't say fill_parent is the ONLY other option.  You can always specify a set width in pixels or dip or something.  You can also set it to 0 and use the layout_weight attribute to control how it expands.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer has already been accepted here but you could have also set the layout_gravity to center too and then wrap_content would still work.